# The transcription with speech_recognition is being cut off midway

Tags: python-3.x, speech-recognition

I would like to output text from a wav file that is about 2 minutes long, but the text is cut off in the middle. The source code is below. How can I solve this problem?

The execution environment is as follows:

- python 3.10.13
- speechrecognition 3.10.0

```py
import speech_recognition as sr

r = sr.Recognizer()
r.pause_threshold = 5
r.dynamic_energy_threshold = False
r.energy_threshold = 200

audio_file = 'horseracing-commentary/data/wav/02_DoncasterMile.wav'

with sr.AudioFile(audio_file) as source:
    audio_data = r.record(source)

# recognize speech using Google Speech Recognition   
try:
    text_data = r.recognize_google(audio_data, language='en-US', show_all=False)

    file_name = audio_file.replace('wav', 'txt')
    f = open(file_name, 'w')
    f.write(text_data)
    f.close()

# Raises a speech_recognition.UnknownValueError exception if the speech is unintelligible.
except sr.UnknownValueError:
    print('Google Speech Recognition could not understand audio')
# Raises a speech_recognition.RequestError exception if the speech recognition operation failed, if the key isn't valid, or if there is no internet connection.
except sr.RequestError as e:
    print('Could not request results from Google Speech Recognition service; {0}'.format(e))
```

I added the following three settings, but the result did not change.
I want to transcribe all the audio in a wav file into text.

```py
r.pause_threshold = 5
r.dynamic_energy_threshold = False
r.energy_threshold = 200
```

Comment: What is the sampling rate of  your `.wav` file (in kHz)?

Comment: Thank you for your response. The sampling rate is 48kHz / 16bit.

Comment: OK, can you print the properties of the `audio_data` variable? I want to check that Python thinks it has the same sampling rate and sampling width (48kHz / 16bit) as the `.wav` file has. When using `r.record()` I have seen some issues on Windows machines where it records at 96kHz, which would explain why your transcript is cut off mid way.

Comment: The properties of the audio_data variable are the following. I think sample_width is not same as the wav file.
`sample_rate: 48000, sample_width: 2`

Comment: Thanks for that information @panco, useful. I think you should run a couple of experiments, passing an _explicit_ `sample_width` parameter to the `record()` function - see the source code for the library on GitHub for how to do this. The values I would try are `1` and `4` - what happens if you do this?